# CPN: Replacing tokens in physical css/js files

Tags: files, tokens, blocks

Hi I have some css / js attached to a box with Code Per Node. CPN creates physical files for the code. In `hook_preprocess_node` I can see the CPN output, for example:

```
$vars['cpn']['css'] = token_replace($vars['cpn']['css']);
$vars['cpn']['js'] = token_replace($vars['cpn']['js']);
```

This successfully replaces the tokens in memory but the physical file is loaded up in the header and so the tokens aren't replaced in there and cause an error. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and [`drupal_add_css`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) have an option to add code "inline".  You can try his in a [`template_preprocess_node`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7):

```
function mytheme_proprocess_node (&$variables)
{
  drupal_add_js($variables['cpn']['js'], 'inline');
  drupal_add_css($variables['cpn']['css'], 'inline');
}
```

If you do this in a theme, then the CPN hook should have already been fired.  If you do it from a module, you may need to play with the module weights to get yours to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok at the time of posting this there is no clean solution. You could pass all the cpn code inline but it isn't as easy as `$vars['cpn']['js']` because this is only the CPN for the node and the CPN for any blocks/boxes on the page is elsewhere. This could get messy and you would have to intercept any CPN js/css that would have normally been added to the page in `hook_js_alter` by removing anything coming from the custom cpn path - messy.

For now (not advised) you can edit the CPNs .module:

- Find `function cpn_save_file($data, $filename)` and add: `if(function_exists('token_replace') $data = token_replace($data);`